# how to get songs of particular album

Tags: android, media-queries, android-mediaplayer

i want to get song of particular album like when i click on an album i should get the songs of that album only. i m getting all albums and when i click on album,i m getting all the songs present on device.not of that album.so please tell me how to do that.i tried many stackoverflow answer but didnt get the answer.

```
public class albumSongs extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    ArrayList<albumInfo>albumSongList=new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView2;
    public albumsongAdapter albumsongAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_album_songs);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("try");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        recyclerView2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2);
        recyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);
        albumsongAdapter = new albumsongAdapter(albumSongList,this);
        SearchView searchView=(SearchView)findViewById(R.id.search);
        recyclerView2.setAdapter(albumsongAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView2.getContext(),
                linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
        recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView2.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        getSongsPerAlbum("");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search_view);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setQueryHint("search songs");
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
                // Return true to allow the action view to expand
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
                // When the action view is collapsed, reset the query
                albumsongAdapter.setSearchResult(albumSongList);
                // Return true to allow the action view to collapse
                return true;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        final List<albumInfo> filteredModelList = filter(albumSongList, newText);
        albumsongAdapter.setSearchResult(filteredModelList);
        return true;
    }


    private List<albumInfo> filter(ArrayList<albumInfo> models, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        final List<albumInfo> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (albumInfo model : models) {
            final String text = model.getX().toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }
    public void getSongsPerAlbum(String AlbumId) {
        final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        final String track_id = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID;
        final String track_no = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK;
        final String track_name = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
        final String artist = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST;
        final String duration = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION;
        final String album = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM;
        final String albumid = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID;
        final String composer = MediaStore.Audio.Media.COMPOSER;
        final String year = MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR;
        final String path = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
        final String date_added = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED;
        String[] columns = new String[]{
                track_id,
                track_no,
                track_name,
                artist,
                duration,
                album,
                albumid,
                composer,
                year,
                path,
                date_added
        };
        // Get all tracks if no album id
        Cursor csr;
        if (AlbumId == null || AlbumId.length() < 1) {
            csr = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, columns,null,null,track_no);
        } else {
            // Doesn't work think media has to be scanned first before albums are generated
            csr = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, columns,album + "=?",new String[]{AlbumId},track_no);
        }

        for (String s: csr.getColumnNames()
                ) {
            Log.d("SONGCOLUMN","Column = " + s);
        }
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            String id = (csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(track_name)));
            String thisalbumId=(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(path)));
            String v = (csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(albumid)));
            Log.d("SONG","Name of Song is " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(track_name)) +
                    " from Album " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(album))
            );

                       albumInfo s = new albumInfo(id, v, thisalbumId);
                       albumSongList.add(s);

        }
        csr.close();
        //  recyclerView2.setAdapter(albumsongAdapter);
    }


}
```

Comment: are you using oreo ?

Comment: i have updated the answer please check and update if it worked..

Answer (score 0):

Use this with your notificationManagerInitialization 
Use this `openActivityNotification(Context context)` function , this is because.. In oreo..

- You need to **create a channel of NotificationChannel type**
- Then add the channel to the notification manager...
  like i did.. `nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_OPEN_ACTIVITY,nc.build());`

  ```
   public static void openActivityNotification(Context context)
   { 
     NotificationCompat.Builder nc = new 
               NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"default");

         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26) {

           nm =
          (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

  }
  else
     {
            nm =
          (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default",
          "Channel name",
          NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
  channel.setDescription("Channel description");

  if (notificationManager != null) {
      nm.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  }
  }
  Intent notifyIntent=new Intent(context, BlankFragment2.class);
  notifyIntent
      .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_
                                                                 TASK);

  PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,notifyIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  nc.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
  nc.setAutoCancel(true);
  nc.setContentTitle("notification demo");
  nc.setContentText("click please");
  nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_OPEN_ACTIVITY,nc.build());

   }
  ```

**Edit**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26) {

             nm =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    }
    else
       {
        nm =(NotificationManager) 
                   context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default",
            "Channel name",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channel.setDescription("Channel description");

    if (notificationManager != null) {
        nm.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    }
```

**Init the notification manager like this** And instead of deprecated notification builder use this...

`NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"default");`

Comment: You have to do the same for custom big notification ... too.,. i am updating for that too.. if you dont understand..

Comment: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control. See the documentation of setSound() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case.

Comment: try to change the notification ID and then use the latest notification.builder compat as i have updated.. and inform..

Comment: i m unable to apply "default" to the Builder.

Comment: then change it something else.. "yourChannel"

Comment: i mean it says cannot apply java.lang.string